# How to do OR operation on one filter's options of Views 3

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have two content-types Courses and Groups. Courses is added as entity reference field in Group content-type. 
One category field is added in courses content-type.

View is created for list of all courses. Category is added as filter. This category has terms. AND operation is applied as default. Like if user has selected term1 and term2 as filters then courses who has both terms selected are only listed. But I want courses who has either term1 or term2 should be listed.
I am using better exposed filter module and checkboxes for category filter options.

Group filter is created for category where I have added terms as :

```
term1, is equal to, term_id
term2, is equal to, term_Id
```

Other options are less than or equal to, greater or equal to, greater than, less than, in between, is empty etc. But no any setting using which I can apply OR operation on single field options.

How can I resolve this issue ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click the arrow next to the criteria and select "And/Or" to change this setting. Here I've added two criteria and set them to "or"

[image: Add/Or]

[image]